# Formal Reduction: Pushdown Automata recognizing context free languages with bounded stack

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, context-free-grammar

I am studying for an exam in automata theory and I am having trouble solving the following:

Consider [pushdown automata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton#Formal_Definition) and [context free languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language). Show that the following decision problem is undecidable by providing a formal reduction from a known undecidable problem.

**Input:** A context free language $\mathcal{L}$ given in form of a grammar $\mathcal{G}$.

**Question:** Is there a push down automaton $\mathcal{P}$ which recognizes $\mathcal{L}$ with bounded stack usage, i.e. there is a bound $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that no run of $\mathcal{P}$ needs more than $k$ symbols on the stack.

**Hint:** The decision problem whether a given context free language $\mathcal{L}$ is regular is undecidable.

My thoughts so far:

- If stack is bounded, push down automata can be transformed into an NFA
- NFA recognize regular languages
- Context free languages are not recognizable by bounded pushdown automata

Comment: As you observed, if there exists a stack-bounded automata, then $\mathcal{L}$ is regular. Moreover, NFA is a stack-bounded automaton (with bound being 0), so this is an "if and only if" connection between existence of appropriate stack-bounded automata and NFAs. This way, given an algorithm that solves your problem, you can tell whether a context free language is regular.

Comment: @dtldarek your comment may be suited for an answer, isn't it?

Comment: @wece Done. ${}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you observed, if there exists a stack-bounded automata, then $\mathcal{L}$ is regular. Moreover, NFA is a stack-bounded automaton (with bound being 0), so this is an "if and only if" connection between existence of appropriate stack-bounded automata and NFAs. This way, given an algorithm that solves your problem, you can tell whether a context free language is regular.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$